# Avoid long list of elif isinstance

Tags: python, isinstance

I have the following construction with a long list of around 100 if .. elif. Is there a way do handle this more elegantly in python?

```
   if isinstance(scen_dep, Class1):
        scen_deps[someEnum.class2].append('1')
   elif isinstance(scen_dep, Class2):
        scen_deps[someEnum.class2].append('1')
   elif isinstance(scen_dep, Class3):
        scen_deps[someEnum.class3].append('1')
```

Comment: Have you considered using a dictionary or similar way of mapping?

Comment: Seems like there should be a method on the specific classes that returns the relevant value.